# Calendar's GregorianCalendar methods setting date to previous day

Tags: java, calendar, gregorian-calendar

I'm having a strange issue with abstract Calendar class using the GregorianCalendar method.

For some reason using "calendar.set" is returning a date from the previous day. 
See code below for example with comments on where it works fine, and where it goes wrong.

```
private Date checkDate(Date d, int hour, int minute, int sec, int milliSec)
{
    // Test values for arguments
    d = "Wed Apr 06 00:00:00 BST 2011";
    hour = minute = sec = milliSec = 0;

    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="UTC",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]);
    calendar.setTime(d);

    // *** OK *** calendar.getTime() will display correctly here (Wed Apr 06 00:00:00 BST 2011)

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, sec);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, milliSec);

    // *** NOT OK *** calendar.getTime() will display inncorrectly here (Tue Apr 05 01:00:00 BST 2011)


return calendar.getTime();
```

}
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: what happens if you change the value for daylight savings time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="UTC",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]);
calendar.setTime(d);
```

Ok, so you have a calendar with its timezone set to UTC and set its time to

`Wed Apr 06 00:00:00 BST 2011`.

Internally, this is mapped to

`2011-04-05 23:00:00 UTC` (the date and time is adopted, the time zone is kept).

Setting the hour, minute, second and millisecond fields of the calendar to 0 will change it to

`2011-04-05 00:00:00 UTC`.

If you now convert the calendar to a `java.util.Date` object and print it while considering your local time zone (BST), the output will be:

`2011-04-05 01:00:00 BST`.

Answer (score 0):

Calendar is a bit strange, as you can read in its javadoc; the bottom line is that you have to call calendare.get() after every time you call a calendar.set(...) or the modification may be inconsistent.